Jenkins UI: User Builds Are Often Mixed Up with Other Users' Builds
The following page in Jenkins is supposed to list the builds started by a specefic user:
https://<jenkins.domain>/user/<username>/builds 
However, this page often includes builds triggered by other users, not just those related to the user (with the specified username in the URL).
There are no errors in the System Log or in the browser, and I'm not sure why this page isn't displaying correctly.
Environment:
Jenkins version: 2.452.1
Authentication mechanism: LDAP
I need a solution to filter or list builds by user in the Jenkins UI. Modifying job configurations is not an option for me.
Any suggestions?
I need the builds for the user with that specific username to be displayed.
